# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype' in code yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names))

Tags: python, python-3.x, yolo

```
yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names))
```

I am trying to execute this code in google collab but getting error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-d69bb71a2d56> in <module>()
----> 1 yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in dtype(x)
903     {{np_implementation}}
904     """
--> 905     return x.dtype.base_dtype.name
906 
907 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

I am trying to detect objects using yolo algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

`yolo_head` expects a numpy array, but you provide it with a built-in Python list.

Comment: Then what should be my numpy array? Please specify

Comment: @Harsh Read the `yolo` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, this error is arriving due to the code you have used in the keras_yolo program which uses an older version of TensorFlow. Google collab uses a recent version of TensorFlow. I would suggest installing the older version of TensorFlow and then running the same program you made for keras_yolo.py.
If you want to make your environment using conda, you can use these commands in your terminal.

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5 jupyter -y
conda install --name tensorflow tensorflow=1.0.0 --channel conda-forge -y
```

If you want still want to continue with google collab you can edit keras_yolo.py file using recent version symbols from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python).

It helped me in making a model for car detection with YOLO.